# For loop inside object javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightgallery

I'm using lightGallery and I'm using dynamic creation of galleries, this is the code to generate just one image:

```
$(this).lightGallery({
    dynamic:true,
    dynamicEl: [{
        'src':'css/images/pictures/gal_'+id+'/1.jpg',
        'thumb':'css/images/thumbnails/gal_'+id+'/1.jpg'
    }]
});
```

This id variable is always the same, but I want to loop through a number which I take for example from variable `x`. So, if `x=4` the code generated would look like this:

```
$(this).lightGallery({
    dynamic:true,
    dynamicEl: [{
        'src':'css/images/pictures/gal_'+id+'/1.jpg', //here's 1
        'thumb':'css/images/thumbnails/gal_'+id+'/1.jpg'
    },{
        'src':'css/images/pictures/gal_'+id+'/2.jpg', //here's 2 and so on
        'thumb':'css/images/thumbnails/gal_'+id+'/2.jpg'
    },{
        'src':'css/images/pictures/gal_'+id+'/3.jpg',
        'thumb':'css/images/thumbnails/gal_'+id+'/3.jpg'
    },{
        'src':'css/images/pictures/gal_'+id+'/4.jpg',
        'thumb':'css/images/thumbnails/gal_'+id+'/4.jpg'
    }]
});
```

So I guess the question is how to include a for loop inside an object, if that's even possible, thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry if this is a newbie question, I'm not that good with jQuery and javascript :(

Comment: Create `array` of `objects` before initializing `lightGallery` and then pass the variable which is holding `array`

Answer (score 1):

No. It's not possible to have control structures(like loops) inside an object definition. You need to create your array of images first, like this:

```
var dynamicEl = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  dynamicEl.push({
    'src':'css/images/pictures/gal_' + id + '/'+ i + '.jpg',
    'thumb':'css/images/thumbnails/gal_' + id + '/' + i + '.jpg'
  });
}
```

And then to pass it onto the object definition:

```
$(this).lightGallery({
    dynamic:true,
    dynamicEl: dynamicEl
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var genEls = function(id, count)
{
    var els = [];
    for(i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        els.push({
            'src':'css/images/pictures/gal_'+ id + '/' + i + '.jpg',
            'thumb':'css/images/thumbnails/gal_' + id + '/' + i + '.jpg',
        });
    }
return els;
}   

var id = 3;
var count = 4;
$(this).lightGallery({
    dynamic:true,
    dynamicEl: genEls(id,count);
});
```

This is as inline as it can get ;)

Hope this helps ...

Comment: I have updated my answer to be more manageable! Please mark it as answer so as other can easily identify what worked for you! Keep up the good work and be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

first create a method to dynamically generate thumbs

```
function genThumbs(count, id)
{
   var arr = [];
   for ( var counter = 1; counter <= count; counter++)
   {
      arr.push( {
        'src':'css/images/pictures/gal_'+id+'/' + counter + '.jpg',
        'thumb':'css/images/thumbnails/gal_'+id+'/' + counter + '.jpg'
      } );
   }
   return arr;
}
```

then use the same while calling the gallery

```
$(this).lightGallery({
    dynamic:true,
    dynamicEl: genThumbs(5, id)
});
```